# How to create record if it does not exist in mongodb during bulkWrite?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The server will receiving lots of data. And issue is that I need to create records if a field name of the record does not exist in the database.

I am using mongoose for performing operations with mongodb.

```
db.getDb(async function (error, db) {
        await db._models.Model.bulkWrite(
          values.map((value) => {
            const instance = new db._models.Model({
              __v: 0,
            });
            return {
              updateOne: {
                filter: {
                  title: value,
                  _datasetId: dataset._id,
                },
                update: {
                  $set: {
                    _id: instance._id,
                    _datasetId: dataset._id,
                    title: tag,
                    createdBy: user._id,
                    createdAt: date,
                    updatedAt: date,
                    __v: instance.__v,
                  },
                },
                upsert: true,
              },
            };
          })
        );
```

I do not want to update existing record, but to create record if it does not exist. (If record with title and _datasetId exist, it should skip the values).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have already set upsert:true  , in case updateOne do not find the document specified by the filter it will perform insert instead of update...

Comment: This is true, but the thing is I do not need to update record...

Comment: If you want to only insert , you can do  insertOne

Comment: Will it be good for bulk write? 
Because I do not want to perform hundred of db calls..